# Grails, launching a modal box from the onclick of a div tag

Tags: grails, html, modal-dialog

I'm very new to grails...

I can create a txt link that launches a modalbox by using:

```
modalbox:createLink url="sample.gsp" title="Hello Grails!" width="600" linkname="This is the Link"
```

What I'm trying to do now is launch the modal from clicking on a div container.

```
<div onclick=modalboxblahblah>

</div>
```

and that doesn't work.  Is there a better solution

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a  surrounding the div. for instance:

```
<modalbox:createLink url="form" title="Test" width="600" linkname="">
    <div>
        Place Anything here
    </div>
</modalbox:createLink>
```